# How to store 64bit number (bitboard)

Tags: php, mysql, chess

I wanted to play around with bitboards for presenting a chessgame.
For presenting a chessgame, i need at least 12, but preferable 14 bitboards with values like:

00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111 11111111

What kind of datatype needed here? I thought i could save it as a biginteger but then i converts to a numerical value?

Comment: Bits and numbers are the same thing to a computer.

Comment: A binary number IS numeric.  What language are you processing it in?  You need bit operations to convert it back to a bit string.  Provided the number is stored as a 64-bit value, your problem is simply to do with textual representation.

Comment: PHP/MySQL. Read a lot about bitboards and bitwise operators for checking the game.Now starting to try it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [BIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/bit-type.html) type to store bit fields.

The type `BIT(14)` will store a field of 14 bits. You write to these fields using the notation `b'01001'`.